# Anywhere I can get a comprehensive list over basic matrix operation rules?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having troubles finding a list over the most basic arithmetic rules of matrices. For example, in a proof using a chain of equivalences, can I choose exactly where to multiply a matrix? Like this:

$$
AB=BA \Longleftrightarrow CAB=CBA \Longleftrightarrow ABC=BAC \Longleftrightarrow ACB=BCA
$$

Are all of these equivalences OK? Or maybe only the first and the second one?

Comment: Usually introductory textbooks on linear algebra explain matrix operations carefully.

Comment: I see. Mine didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That chain of equivalences is correct, for the most part. What you can say is this $$AB=BA\Leftrightarrow CAB=CBA\\ AB=BA \Leftrightarrow ABC=BAC$$ with $C\neq 0$ and, as the user [cdwe](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/347301/cdwe) pointed out, only if $C$ is invertible (see the counterexample in the comments). If you say $$CAB=CBA\Leftrightarrow ABC=BAC$$ **without implying that $A$ and $B$ commute**, is not always true, because what you're saying is that $C[A,B]=0$ is the same thing as $[A,B]C=0$ and this is only true if the matrix $C$ and  the matrix $[A,B]$ commute with one another or that $[C,[A,B]]=0$ (or $C$ could simply be the null matrix, but that's a special case because the zero matrix commutes with every matrix).

So to put it in a better way

> If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices such that $[A,B] =0$ then $[C,[A,B]]=0$

On a side note, you have that if $[C,[A,B]]=0$, then $[A,[B,C]]+[B,[C,A]]=0$ directly from the Jacobi identity that says $$[A,[B,C]]+[B,[C,A]]+[C,[A,B]]=0$$

The third equivalence is not right at all: you could either multiply on the *left* or multiply on the *right*, there's no such rule for multiplication *"in the middle"*, just take as an example $A=I$ and $$B=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right) \\ C=\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right)$$ you can easily check that $A$ and $B$ commute but $ACB \neq BCA$

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Choose matrices $A$ and $B$ that do not commute and choose $C$ the zero matrix. The first two equivalences do not hold.

Comment: @cdwe Oh yes, you're right! I forgot to mention that, I'll add it straight away, thanks!

Comment: @cdwe Mhhhh..you're right again.. so it seems like that "if and only if" cannot be true, only the right implication is. I'm sorry for the confusion, I'm correcting the answer, thanks!

Comment: @DavideMorgante sorry for the confusion, $C \neq 0$ does not fix the equivalences. Try $A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$, $B = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$, $C = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $ABC = BAC$, but $AB \neq BA$. But if $C$ is invertible, the first two equivalences do indeed hold, which can easily be verified by multiplying by it's inverse.